# asp.net core appears to freeze when debugging application

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first, asp.net-core

Has anyone seen the issue when debugging an Asp.Net 5 (core) application where the application seems to just go to sleep. Selecting another function/page in the browser just says "Waiting for LocalHost" (as I am running it locally on IIS Express).

We have a staged version of the Asp.Net app and it has no such problem. It runs wonderfully, but in Debug mode, it can have serious delay issues in executing code. Nothing is reported in the output window, during the time it appears to be doing nothing. Nothing on the Diagnostic tools windows either

A lot of the time - it will ultimately come back if you let it do its thing. But sometimes it can take up to 15-30 seconds. 
The issue seems to become more prevalent when you change the Razor or javascript client files while the app is running?

Soemtimes pressing F5 on the web page makes it get out of its sleep mode (but not always, and it seems the more times you do this it, the slower it gets). Is it perhaps rebuilding the page that changed? but why the delay?

Again this works fine in Staging or Production (as none of the back end client side files would be changing). But it can be very annoying

Any ideas?

Comment: Had a similar problem I resolved by installing VS 2015 Update 2 and the web tool extension update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found I didn't have the web tool extensions even installed - and after I installed it - the Freeze disappeared, but a colleague of mine still has the problem (as he already had the extension loaded and there is no way to uninstall it once its loaded

Answer (score 0):

For me it was my Anti Virus. As soon as I disable AVG all requests get immediately run by the debugger.